# Docker compose Mongo data not being saved

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to create a Docker compose file with mongo DB, saving all the data to the folder as a volume, so I can share the the project, with the data included.

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
    - data:/data/db
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: pass
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: pass
    depends_on:
      - mongo
volumes:
  data;
```

The docker containers launch just fine and I'm able to create collections. However my local data folder is empty.

I've tried...

```
    volumes:
    - ./data:/data/db
```

...as well.

But still I don't see the data.

Am I missing something?

Comment: have you try to insert anything to the collection? the docker-compose looks good.

Comment: Could you try to add :rw  like - ./data:/data/db:rw, but delete ./data on local before rerunning compose

Comment: I've added things to the collection, but nothing shows up. I will try the :rw, though